# Change Setting Menu Link in the Admin Navigation menu in OpenCart 2.x

Tags: php, admin, opencart2.x

I need to change one of the links in the admin navigation menu, specifically the settings item to be transferred to the default store directly.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution..

I changed the link in the admin\controller\template\common\menu

```
$data['setting'] = $this->url->link('setting/setting', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');
```

and changed the following in the admin\model\template\setting\setting

```
public function editStore($store_id= 0, $data) {
        $this->event->trigger('pre.admin.store.edit', $data);

        $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "store SET name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['config_name']) . "', `url` = '" . $this->db->escape($data['config_url']) . "', `ssl` = '" . $this->db->escape($data['config_ssl']) . "' WHERE store_id = 0'"); //      $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "store SET name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['config_name']) . "', `url` = '" . $this->db->escape($data['config_url']) . "', `ssl` = '" . $this->db->escape($data['config_ssl']) . "' WHERE store_id = '" . (int)$store_id . "'");

        $this->cache->delete('store');

        $this->event->trigger('post.admin.store.edit', $store_id);
    }
```